# cURL post multiple fields along with file - form fields not displaying

Tags: node.js, express, curl

I'm trying to POST multiple form fields, mixed with a file field, to my Node App, ver 7.4.0, using Express 4.0, but the fields aren't coming through to the server in the `req` object.

```
curl -X POST -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data' -F 'userEmail=my@gmail.com' -F upload=@/Users/me/Desktop/test_docs/doc1.xlsx localhost:5000/api/payments
```

But when I log `console.log('REQ', req.body);`, I get `{ }`, when I expected at least `userEmail` present in the `req.body`.

I'm using `bodyParser` middleware as recommended

```
  app.use(bodyParser.json());
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ // to support URL-encoded bodies
    extended: true,
  }));
```

Why isn't the form field coming through? Yet, if I post as `application/JSON`, I can see the fields in `req.body`.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation of [`body-parser`](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser):

> This does not handle multipart bodies, due to their complex and
>   typically large nature. For multipart bodies, you may be interested in
>   the following modules: busboy, connect-busboy, multiparty,
>   connect-multiparty, formidable, multer.

For example if `multer`:

```
// /api/payments.js

var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var multer  = require('multer')
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })

/* POST /api/payments */
router.post('/payments', upload.single('upload'), function(req, res, next) {
  res.json( req.body )
});
```